# Feasible node version for react 16.x? CSR (client-side rendered page)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Planning to migrate the CSR(client-side rendered) application form React 15 to 16.X. 
Please suggest me, what would be the feasible node version for React 16.X migration?

Answer (score 3):

React is not dependent on a specific node version. So I would suggest to go with the Long Term Support version and upgrade if you need anything from newer veresions. LTS as of this writing is [8.11.4](https://nodejs.org/en/). Popular libraries like Create-React-App by facebook use node v8 and v10.